# Mysql self join in View

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, mapping

I am facing issue related to One to Many relation MySql Table.

[image]

```
Table: Employee  {Columns: Code, Email, Supervisor(e.g. Code1, Code2, Code3), Hr1(Self-join with the employee), Hr1(Self-join with the employee)}
```

My Requirement is: We want to send birthday mail to all employees for the current date and that mail also we want to send employee supervisor and Hr with CC and BCC respectively.

So I want to create one view to fetch all the email ID linked with the employee just like the supervisor(BCC: Test@gmail.com) and HR(CC: Test@gmail.com).

So how to self-join the supervisor and Hr to achieve the Email Id in One row.

```
   View ==> ViewEmployee : {Columns : EmployeeEmail, SupervisorEmail, HREmail }
```

So no need to fetch all the table field.

Please help me anyone know this.

Thanks
Sitansu

Comment: It would help your question to show some sample data and expected output, both in tabular form.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Updated the  Question

Comment: _Don't_ store CSV data in your tables.  This will make querying your data difficult and/or not possible.  And also, please include your data as text, formatted as code, not an embedded image.

Comment: Are you using Oracle or MySQL?

Comment: @mysql We are using

Comment: @Sitansu then Oracle tag you should remove ;)